# Do I need to generate a controller for a Ruby on Rails Controller call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm setting a session variable to a user's geographical state. I have to use a session variable because I run code on the server specific to that user on page load and I need to know where they are. This code is set up to just update the session variable.

states_controller.rb

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  def loc
    session[:location] = params[:location]
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
post "states/loc" => "states#loc"
```

The code routes properly and the session variable is updated.

However, when the process is complete I get a 500 error in the console "Missing Template" in the views directory. I haven't seen any tutorials tell users to call the command "rails generate controller" and I'm in the unique situation where I can't call this command.

What possible side effect are there to ignoring this 500 error?

*I'm running an older version of ruby and rails.

Comment: as `loc` action is a `post` verb i don't have view page.so it can't render any template.so you need to redirect to some where else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What possible side effect are there to ignoring this 500 error?

Each request is crashing your rails server. Thats not good. Since it means  that some cases it may have to restart after every failed request - that eats resources like Homer Simpson at a buffet.

Your app should not be raising uncaught exceptions that cause 500 errors - thats just decent professional practice.

#### So how do I fix it?

Simple, if you don't want the default behavior of rendering a view tell rails to do something else:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  def loc
    session[:location] = params[:location]
    head :created
  end
end
```

This sends an empty response with the `201 - CREATED` http header.

See [Rails Guides - Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#creating-responses)

Comment: There's also the `render(nothing: true)` option.